# Does the ObjectCreate initialize [[Prototype]] and [[Extensible]] twice?

Tags: ecmascript-6

When I was reading the ECMAScript spec (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-objectcreate), I found this sentence:

> 3. Set obj's essential internal methods to the default ordinary object definitions specified in 9.1

followed by

> 4. Set obj.[[Prototype]] to proto.
> 5. Set obj.[[Extensible]] to true.

However, in 9.1, it describes how [[Prototype]] and [[Extensible]] are initialized, so why are steps 4 and 5 necessary?

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence which I think is supposed to be the essence of your question.

Comment: Hope my edits are cool, I think this is a fair question, it just needed a little clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the header of `9.1`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours)

> All ordinary objects have an internal slot called [[Prototype]].

and

> Every ordinary object has a Boolean-valued [[Extensible]] internal slot.

vs

> Each ordinary object internal method ...

So in the section that you've linked, there's the distinction between **methods** and **slots**.

- `[[Prototype]]` and `[[Extensible]]` are **slots**.
- `[[GetPrototypeOf]]()`, `[[GetOwnProperty]](P)` and all the rest are **methods**.

In the snippets you've posted, step 3 specifically states that it initializes the **methods**. `[[Prototype]]` and `[[Extensible]]` are internal **slots**, so they are initialize separately in steps 4 and 5.

In addition, I'd say that while internal methods are generally static and defined by the spec, internal slots are mutable and don't necessarily have clear default values, so while it makes sense to broadly initialize the methods, the same isn't really the case for slots.

Comment: You write that there is a difference between **methods** and **slots**. But then you write that the **methods are slots**. What does it mean?

Comment: internal slot - `[[slot]]`, internal method - `[[method]]()`. So `[[Prototype]]` and `[[Extensible]]` are slots not methods! They have simple value not a function.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your answer :)

Comment: I updated to try to be clearer. The key thing is that internal methods are separate from slots, like your second comment says.

Comment: Well, now I understand you. But still there is not clarity. If you say that: "In the snippets you've posted, step 3 specifically states that it initializes the methods. `[[Prototype]]` and `[[Extensible]]` are internal slots, so they are initialize separately in steps 4 and 5." What methods are initialized in 9.1?

Comment: I correctly understand that the initialization of methods is from 9.1.1 to 9.1.11 (what enclosed in double square brackets). Right?

Comment: Each item that has its own header 9.1 with `[[...]]()` in the name is a method, like `[[GetPrototypeOf]]()`.

Comment: I already understood that! I'm talking about the fact that in paragraph 3 it is said about the initialization of internal methods for the object. These methods are from 9.1.1 to 9.1.14.

Comment: Correct. What is your question then?

Comment: Then there is no more questions :)